# Given indexes, get values from numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have this numpy matrix:

```
>>> mat = np.matrix([[3,4,5,2,1], [1,2,7,6,5], [8,9,4,5,2]])
>>> mat
matrix([[3, 4, 5, 2, 1],
        [1, 2, 7, 6, 5],
        [8, 9, 4, 5, 2]])
```

Now let's say I have some indexes in this form:

```
>>> ind = np.matrix([[0,2,3], [0,4,2], [3,1,2]])
>>> ind
matrix([[0, 2, 3],
        [0, 4, 2],
        [3, 1, 2]])
```

What  I would like to do is to get three values from each row of the matrix, specifically values at columns 0, 2, and 3 for the first row, values at columns 0, 4 and 2 for the second row, etc. This is the expected output:

```
matrix([[3, 5, 2],
        [1, 5, 7],
        [5, 9, 4]])
```

I've tried using `np.take` but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html).

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(mat, ind, axis=1)
matrix([[3, 5, 2],
        [1, 5, 7],
        [5, 9, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it: `mat[np.arange(3).reshape(-1, 1), ind]`

```
In [245]: mat[np.arange(3).reshape(-1, 1), ind]
Out[245]: 
matrix([[3, 5, 2],
        [1, 5, 7],
        [5, 9, 4]])
```

(but `take_along_axis` in @user3483203's answer is simpler).